# How to let deserialization throw exception on non-integer where expecting an int?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I am trying to parse a decimal value from json (eg. `id: 4.5`) to a poco `int` and I want an exception.

### Background:

This deserialization throws `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` when encountering a decimal where expecting an `int`:

```
httpContent.ReadAsAsync<MyCollection<T>>(
                mediaTypeFormatters,
                cancellationToken);
```

`MyCollection<T>` is a class with a list `Result` of type `T`, and `T` can have an `int`. Now, I want to catch the ones that throw and keep the rest. So I first extract it as a collection of `JObject` instead, and then parse them one by one in a try-catch.

```
var jObjectsMyCollection = await httpContent.ReadAsAsync<MyCollection<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>>(
            mediaTypeFormatters,
            cancellationToken);
foreach (var j in jObjectsMyCollection.Results) {
    try {
        // now let's parse j one by one
```

### The problem is

I can not make it throw this way, even using the same formatter:

This just deserializes the `4.5` to `4` and does not throw:

```
var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(myMediaTypeFormatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);
j.ToObject<T>(jsonSerializer)
```

Same with this:

```
var ser = myMediaTypeFormatters.JsonFormatter.CreateJsonSerializer();
tObjects.Add(ser.Deserialize<T>(j.CreateReader()));
```

For the record, the two different formatters used in the different are set up like this:

```
myMediaTypeFormatters= new MediaTypeFormatterCollection();
myMediaTypeFormatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Error += SerializationErrorHander;
myMediaTypeFormatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new SnakeCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
myMediaTypeFormatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;

IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> mediaTypeFormatters = myMediaTypeFormatters;
```

### The Question:

How can I make it throw at exactly the same data as `ReadAsAsync` does?
Am I doing soemthing wrong in reusing the MediaTypeFormatters?

Comment: Can you share a full [mcve] that reproduces your problem -- i.e. with an example type `T`?

Comment: Hi dbc. No, I got no other exceptions. MCVE makes sense. I will try to return with that.

Comment: OK, MCVE here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VjGRn2

Answer (score 5):

Json.NET does seem to have inconsistencies in how it converts floating-point JSON values to integers.  E.g., using 10.0.2:

- `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>("4.5")` **fails**.
- `JToken.Parse("4.5").ToObject<int>()` **succeeds** and returns 4.
- `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<uint>("4.5")` **succeeds** and returns 4.
- `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<long>("4.5")` **succeeds** and returns 4.

(In fact, directly deserializing `"4.5"` to an `int` seems to be the only case that fails. Json.NET will deserialize `"4.5"` directly or indirectly to any other integral type.)

The difference seems to arise from inconsistencies between [`JsonTextReader.ParseReadNumber()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1915) (which is called when deserializing JSON directly) and [`JsonReader.ReadAsInt32()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs#L416) (which is called when deserializing from a `JToken`).  The former checks that the textual JSON value is really an integer when deserializing to an `int` while the latter simply calls [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130995(v=vs.110).aspx) which happily returns a rounded value.

If you want, you could [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about the inconsistency.

In the meantime, you have a couple of options to avoid the inconsistency.  Firstly, you could introduce a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for integers that throws an exception when trying to deserialize a floating point value to an integer, then use that when deserializing from a `JToken` hierarchy:

```
public class StrictIntConverter : StrictIntConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int) || objectType == typeof(int?);
    }
}

public abstract class StrictIntConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            if (isNullable)
                return null;
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for {0}", objectType));
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Floating-point value {0} found for {1}.", reader.Value, type));
        }
        else
        {
            // Integer or string containing an integer
            if (reader.Value.GetType() == type)
                return reader.Value;
            return JToken.Load(reader).ToObject(type);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(myMediaTypeFormatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
jsonSerializer.Converters.Add(new StrictIntConverter());    
j.ToObject<T>(jsonSerializer)
```

Sample [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LsKb21).

Another option would be to use Json.NET's [serialization error handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationerrorhandling.htm) to catch and swallow exceptions when deserializing collection items inside your `MyCollection<T>` type, for instance:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    [OnError]
    void OnError(StreamingContext context, ErrorContext errorContext)
    {
        if (errorContext.OriginalObject != this)
        {
            // Error occurred deserializing an item in the collection.  Swallow it.
            errorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to deserialize directly to your `MyCollection<T>` and skip the intermediate `JToken` representation.  Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RCNLBx).