# Is it possible to keep JSON.NET from converting a serialized value to a more permissable type?

Tags: json.net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string someSerializedValue = "{\"SomeValue\":true}";
    var stringBool = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StringBool>(someSerializedValue);
    var actualBool = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActualBool>(someSerializedValue);
}

private class StringBool
{
    // I want this to fail
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}

private class ActualBool
{
    public bool SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `SomeValue` is a boolean `true` in JSON. So I'd like the deserialization step to fail for `stringBool`. But it doesn't. Is there an attribute that will be more strict about what valid deserialization is in cases like this?

Comment: Out of curiousity if you control the deserialization property names and types how would this ever be an issue?

Comment: Yes, that's the point: the type isn't being respected. JSON.NET is deserializing `{"SomeValue":true}` into `string SomeValue = "true"`. If the client were sending `{"SomeValue":"true"}`, that would be make sense. But they're not. So yes, I control the type, but the serializer is doing something unexpected here WRT types. (It does the same thing with numbers.)

Comment: You could create `StrictStringConverter` along the lines of `StrictIntConverter` from [JSON Deserialization - String Is Automatically Converted To Int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41784433) and [How to let deserialization throw exception on non-integer where expecting an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777434).